# Using User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5) in Tibco BW

Tags: tibco

I am trying to invoke Kelly Blue Book Web Service using Tibco BW. I observed that KBB accepts HTTP requests only from Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5) but Tibco always uses Jakarta Http client internally.

is their a way that we can use Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5) in Tibco BW.

Answer (score 3):

You can spoof the User-Agent by setting a "User-Agent" dynamic header in input of the [`Send HTTP Request`](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/5.10.0_june_2012/doc/html/tib_bw_palette_reference/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#context=tib_bw_palette_reference&file=palref.5.073.htm) activity.

Comment: your welcome @user3063230. Please accept the answer by clicking on the tick over to the left of the answer