# How to disable user-agent on HTTP request header on spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, http, tomcat, http-headers, user-agent

I'm developing a spring boot application , when I do a GET/POST HTTPS request from SOAP UI/POST-MAN to my contoller method I see user-agent and it's value is being set on HTTP request header which is exposing JAVA version , Is there any way I can override this User-Agent in spring boot not to expose the user-agent

This is something not setting anywhere in the code and it is being set automatically , I tried intercepting the tom-cat start up but no luck

thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example of the `User-Agent` header that is being set? It should be coming from the client side (SOAP UI or Postman in your case), so I wouldn't expect to see any mention of a Java version in there.

Comment: Hello Andy , This is what I am seeing under the raw request on SOAP-UI
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

Comment: When I call from SOAPUI it is setting user-agent as Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5) , and I am using java 8  JDK

Comment: You can customize the User-Agent by setting any dynamic header of the HTTP Request activity ....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361555/using-user-agent-apache-httpclient-4-1-1-java-1-5-in-tibco-bw

Comment: This was being set by the client , thanks and appreciate for all the responses :)